# Random array value in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Hello and I might be making a stupid mistake here, but I was wondering if anyone could help me out! I'm supposed to store values in an array with the size of 20, using a given algorithm, but after my 8th digit, I keep getting some large number that doesn't seem to make sense to me...

```
for(loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < MAX_SIZE; loopCounter++)
{
    //Fun array is computed using the algorithm " fun[i] = 7 * i^2 - 4 * i - 500 ".
    fun[loopCounter] = (7 * (loopCounter * loopCounter)) - (4 * loopCounter) - 500;

    //Output

    cout << fun[loopCounter];

}
```

(MAX_SIZE is declared to 20)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Put your code as text in your question. Also: how it `fun` defined?

Comment: As a general rule, I prefer to call my loop index variables `i`, `j`, `k`.  If you'd done that, you wouldn't need the comment, because it would (very nearly) duplicate the code.  (This has nothing to do with your problem, hence it's a comment).

Comment: looks [fine](https://ideone.com/JsuxqB) to me.

Comment: You may want to check for overflow.  Computing large numbers that overflow could result in weird numbers printed.

Comment: How is `fun` declared?

Answer (score 0):

After running your code in Visual Studio I've noticed something. Your code runs perfectly as you would expect. The only problem here is that this pseudo-random number generator always generates positive numbers from index eight of your array. So it looks like one big number. So if you add << endl; at the end of your cout line, you will see the result perfectly.

```
for (int loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < MAX_SIZE; loopCounter++){

    fun[loopCounter] = (7 * (loopCounter * loopCounter)) - (4 * loopCounter) - 500;
    std::cout << fun[loopCounter] << std::endl;
}
```